# C# - Solving potential deadlock solution

Tags: c#, wpf, deadlock

I have a LongOperationHelper that I activate on each potentially long operation. 
It displays a semi transparent layer and does not allow any click until the operation ends and a spinning control to indicate progress.

It looks something like that (missing some business logic but the idea is clear I think):

**Edited:** (Added the missing code of the common states that actually needed the locking - this is more like the problematic code)

**(My solution is posted in an answer bellow)**

```
public static class LongOperationHelper
{
    private static object _synchObject = new object();
    private static Dictionary<string, int> _calls = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    private static Action<string> DisplayLongOperationRequested;
    private static Action<string> StopLongOperationRequested;

    public static void Begin(string messageKey)
    {
        lock (_synchObject)
        {
            if (_calls.ContainsKey(messageKey))
            {
                _calls[messageKey]++;
            }
            else
            {
                _calls.Add(messageKey, 1);

                DispatcherHelper.InvokeIfNecesary(() =>
                {
                    //Raise event for the MainViewModel to display the long operation layer
                    DisplayLongOperationRequested?.Invoke(messageKey);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    public static void End(string messageKey)
    {
        lock (_synchObject)
        {
            if (_calls.ContainsKey(messageKey))
            {
                if (_calls[messageKey] > 1)
                {
                    _calls[messageKey]--;
                }
                else
                {
                    _calls.Remove(messageKey);

                    DispatcherHelper.InvokeIfNecesary(() =>
                    {
                        //Raise event for the MainViewModel to stop displaying the long operation layer
                        StopLongOperationRequested?.Invoke(messageKey);
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot End long operation that has not began");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can probably see, there is a potential deadlock in there, if:

1. Someone calls Begin from a non UI thread.
2. It enters the lock
3. Someone calls Begin or End from a UI thread and gets locked
4. The first Begin call tries to Dispatch to the UI thread.

Result: Deadlock!

I want to make this Helper thread safe, so that any thread might call Begin,  or End at any given time, interested to see if there is any known pattern, any Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `async/await` instead of locks and Invoke. You don't need them. Post the code you use in `Begin`, `End` or how you report progress. It should be easy to call anything that takes a long time with `await Task.Run(whatever);` and update the UI before/after the `await` statement. You can use the `IProgress<T>` to report progress from another thread without requiring Invoke ro the dispatcher

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the lock at all here.

Comment: @Eibi it won't work properly until you *remove* all that code. Post the *actual* code if you want people to give specific help. Otherwise all one can do is post some generic code. This `Helper` *causes* the problem and isn't needed

Comment: @Eibi: The delegates that you pass to Dispatcher.Invoke will be queued and executed sequentially on the same dispatcher thread so why are you using a lock in the first place?

Comment: I need the lock because as I have mentioned there is logic inside the lock that modifies other fields such as lists and other local states that needs to be protected from reading and writing.

Comment: I will modify the code to show the need for thread synchronization.

Comment: @Eibi you *don't* need a lock, you can use one of the concurrent collections if needed. Or you could modify your code so it *doesn't* modify a global list. It could produce the data it wants locally and return it from the background task. You *should never, ever* use a lock when you use the dispatcher anyway - you are trying to invode something on the same thread you just locked. In any case you haven't showed anything that runs in the background.

Comment: @Eibi you've shown how you attempted to solve some problem but you didn't explain what that problem is. The code you posted doesn't solve anything. *Do* you have a background thread or task? How do you start it? Does it have to produce output? Access global state? Why should it do so?

Comment: Suggestion:  It isn't wise to leave the current method from within a lock.  You should hold the lock as short of time as possible and you shouldn't call any other methods.  You definitely don't jump threads by calling the Dispatcher.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Puckett II, totally agree! therefore I have taken the UI dispatcher code out of the lock and left it minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the "Deadlock free" code:
I have relocated the dispatching to the UI thread to outside of the lock.

(Can someone still see a potential deadlock here?)

```
public static class LongOperationHelper
{
    private static object _synchObject = new object();
    private static Dictionary<string, int> _calls = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    private static Action<string> DisplayLongOperationRequested;
    private static Action<string> StopLongOperationRequested;

    public static void Begin(string messageKey)
    {
        bool isRaiseEvent = false;

        lock (_synchObject)
        {
            if (_calls.ContainsKey(messageKey))
            {
                _calls[messageKey]++;
            }
            else
            {
                _calls.Add(messageKey, 1);

                isRaiseEvent = true;
            }
        }

        //This code got out of the lock, therefore cannot create a deadlock
        if (isRaiseEvent)
        {
            DispatcherHelper.InvokeIfNecesary(() =>
            {
                //Raise event for the MainViewModel to display the long operation layer
                DisplayLongOperationRequested?.Invoke(messageKey);
            });
        }
    }

    public static void End(string messageKey)
    {
        bool isRaiseEvent = false;

        lock (_synchObject)
        {
            if (_calls.ContainsKey(messageKey))
            {
                if (_calls[messageKey] > 1)
                {
                    _calls[messageKey]--;
                }
                else
                {
                    _calls.Remove(messageKey);

                    isRaiseEvent = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot End long operation that has not began");
            }
        }

        //This code got out of the lock, therefore cannot create a deadlock
        if (isRaiseEvent)
        {
            DispatcherHelper.InvokeIfNecesary(() =>
            {
                StopLongOperationRequested?.Invoke(messageKey);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't lock for the entire method. Lock only when you touch the fields that need it, and unlock as soon as you're done. Lock and unlock each time you touch those fields. Otherwise, you'll end up with deadlocks like this.

You can also consider using [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim), which differentiates between read locks and write locks. It lets multiple threads read at the same time, but locks everyone out when a write lock is taken. There is an example on how to use it in that documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The entire purpose of having a "UI thread" is to avoid synchronization exactly like this.  The fact that all UI code needs to run on a single thread means that it, by definition, cannot run concurrently.  You have no need to use locks to make your UI code run atomically *because it's all running on a single thread*.

Writing UI code that required the programmer to do their own locking is sufficiently hard and error prone that the whole framework was designed around the idea that it's unreasonable to expect people to do it (correctly), and that it's much easier to simply force all UI code to go into a single thread, where other synchronization mechanisms won't be needed.

Comment: The calls to this helper does not "all running on a single thread" as you say, they can be called from background thread as well. hence the synchronization needed.

Comment: @Eibi It doesn't matter where the calls are coming from.  The code does nothing but schedule the code to run on the UI thread, which is *a single thread*.  So all of the meaningful code *is* running on a single thread.

Comment: If by "meaningful code" you are refferring to the code that registered to those events and does the actual display (WPF binding in that case) than I agree, it runs on the UI thread (which is single :)). but as an infrastructure, this helper must be thread safe.

Comment: @Eibi Editing your question into a completely different question is not an appropriate thing to do.

Comment: I most certainly didn't. I agree that it was missing some details therefore the editing :). I just added the reason for the lock in form of some internal states (Dictionary in that case). It is still the same question for me.

Comment: @Eibi Completely changing the code to be synchronized *radically* changes the question of how to synchronize it.  That's like saying, "how do I cook this recipe?" is the same question if you change the recipe to a completely different recipe.  Asking the same question about two completely different code snippets *are different questions*.

Comment: Honestly speaking and with all due respect, I really can't understand some negative reactions sometimes. I do my best to share experience and knowledge (that's the idea, isn't it?). I did everything to make the question and the answer as clear as possible (missed the first time and then edited and fixed it). By your answer, you have missed my point in this question. Can't you see the efforts of sharing thoughts that's in here? Sadly, these kind of reactions makes me want to delete my question entirely..

Comment: @Eibi I precisely answered the question that you asked.  That you intended to ask a *radically* different question doesn't change the fact that you didn't ask that question.  Your question wasn't *unclear*, the answer just wasn't useful to  you because your actual problem was so different from the one you asked about.  Editing your question into an entirely different question is not the appropriate response to that.

Comment: Sorry, but I think I would know if you answered my question. I know what I asked, before and after the change. That part was not changed. The question remained: How to be thread safe to avoid that deadlock? It was before and it is now. How do you think you helped me?! I asked for help to find a way to be thread safe and avoid deadlocks.

Comment: @Eibi The answer to your original question was to remove the locks.  They were unnecessary for properly synchronizing the work that you were doing, and removing them removes the deadlock.  That was the solution to your problem.  You then changed the problem, which changes the answer.  That the answer to your original question isn't helpful to you is because your question wasn't representative of your problem, not because the answer didn't answer it.